# SVN Migration of a big repository

Tags: svn

I have to migrate a quite big svn repository (~20 Gig).
I know that there is option of export import the svn dump.

My Question is that instead of exporting-importing, is there any way that i can point the new svn to use the old storage location instead of completely migrating the repo. (Kind of pointers to storage locaiton)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Subversion server process will assume that the repository is stored on the local machine.  The general thought is that if the data is stored on a different server, you'd simply run the server process on that server.  There are some shady things you could do to try and hack around this, but the result would be an extremely slow repository that would likely have a lot of hard-to-debug problems.

If your problem revolves around not wanting to mess with a 20+ gigabyte dump file, I recommend [using the `svnsync` command to create a mirror of the repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) instead of doing a dump/load.  This will create a second repository that's an exact copy of the first.  The data will copy over incrementally so you won't have any giant files to wrangle.  Once the mirror process is complete, you can simply shut down the old repository and give your users the URL to the new one.  I've been using this method to migrate a repository's contents for several years now.  It can take longer, but most of the process runs automatically so you can leave it running unattended.  The only tricky part is making sure that you have the new server set up with the same credentials, configuration, hook scripts, etc as the old one (the sync process only copies repository contents, not configuration data).